# Upgrade graphics card

Tags: graphics, steam

I have a Pentium dual core ES 8000 at 3.20 GHz my graphics card is a nvidia GF or GeForce GT 430 with 1 GB of ram

What would be the best graphic card to get for my PC so I can run games such as dayz arma 2 on Ubuntu ?

Or the most compatible one with ubuntu  for drivers and easy installation. I have installed [steam [image: Install steam]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steam-launcher) and there are some graphic issues with it.

So I would like to install a graphics card that will work with **steam** and **ubuntu**.

Answer (score 0):

That card should be enough for running Arma 2 - not in high resolution or with lots of details, but it should run just fine (it was released in 2009). NVIDIA is probably the best bet for graphics card on Linux, because they recently started cooperate with Valve on Steam for Linux and the result are new NVIDIA drivers [with much better performance](http://nvidianews.nvidia.com/Releases/NVIDIA-Delivers-Massive-Performance-Boost-to-Linux-Gaming-8ac.aspx).

The problem is that Arma 2 is not yet supported by Steam and it might never be, so your only current option is running it through Wine, and well, see the [support page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10054) for yourself - current status is *garbage*.

Linux is good for indie games (Braid, Swords & Soldiers and other gems from HumbleBundles), but not yet fit for mainstream AAA games. Steam for Linux and Steambox might change that (and I sincerely hope they will), but for now, you'll be much better of with Ubuntu and Windows dualboot.